# With aws_s3_bucket_object deprecated, should I upload files using aws_s3_bucket only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

There's a note on the `aws_s3_bucket_object` page saying it's deprecated and to use `aws_s3_bucket` instead:

> The aws_s3_bucket_object resource is DEPRECATED and will be removed in
> a future version! Use aws_s3_object instead, where new features and
> fixes will be added. When replacing aws_s3_bucket_object with
> aws_s3_object in your configuration, on the next apply, Terraform will
> recreate the object. If you prefer to not have Terraform recreate the
> object, import the object using aws_s3_object.

When I go over to the `aws_s3_bucket` page, there's no example of how to upload a file, only how to create a bucket. A number of articles online also point to use `aws_s3_bucket` to create the bucket but still use `aws_s3_bucket_object` to upload files, is this still the correct practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation of the [`aws_s3_object`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object) and compare it to the documentation of the older [`aws_s3_bucket_object`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object), you can see that they are very similar. If you are using some online tutorial for Terraform, switching `aws_s3_bucket_object` to `aws_s3_object` in the code will probably work without major issue.

Obviously, you will face issues, if you already applied a plan and decide to switch `aws_s3_bucket_object` to `aws_s3_object`. In this case you need to [import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object#import) the object into the current state.

Currently the latest AWS provider is 4.9.0, which marks `aws_s3_bucket_object` as deprecated, but not removed. As long as you don't plan to upgrade the provider, your code will work. If you want to future-proof your code, you will need to use `aws_s3_object`.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the `aws_s3_object` entry

Comment: yeah Google failed me on this too, I ended up on the "Datasource" aws_s3_object instead of the "Resource" aws_s3_object. Which is confusing since the the Datasource version doesn't have the same parameters.

Comment: Switching aws_s3_bucket_object to aws_s3_object in the code worked for me.